# Do you need a "but" when you use the construction "the more ... because"?

Tags: grammar

> The hotel had no computers, an absence **the more regretted**,
>   **because** not only was I completely addicted, **but** it also turned out that it would rain during the whole weekend there.

I am wondering if the particular expression "the more X" implied that you need to put a but. I suppose so, because then the more wouldn't make sense as I believe it means "the more x than usual".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "but" is not relevant to the "the more X" part, but rather to the "not only" part. To be more specific and clear - "not only....but [it] also..." is the construction that the "but" is part of. Here, "the more" means just "more than usually".